# Java game, FPS drops from 300 to 1

Tags: java, runtime-error, lag, 2d-games

I have a problem with my game and i can't find the problem, my FPS drops from 300 to 1, every second like 5 to 10 FPS lower until it's unplayable.
 it gives me an error first at wave.myFirstGame.Handler.removeObject(Handler.java:31) the games starts but crashes. but when i delete the code that gives me this error the game works but the FPS drops and still it's unplayable.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class BasicEnemy extends GameObject {

private Handler handler;


public BasicEnemy(int x, int y, ID id, Handler handler) {
    super(x, y, id);

    this.handler = handler;

    velX = 5;
    velY = 5;

}

public Rectangle getBounds() { //for collision

    return new Rectangle(x, y, 16, 16);
}

public void tick() {
    x += velX;
    y += velY;
    if (y <= 0 || y >= Game.HEIGHT - 32)
        velY *= -1; // limits of the screen for the enemy

    if (x <= 0 || x >= Game.WIDTH - 16)
        velX *= -1;

    handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y,ID.Trail, Color.red, 16, 16, 0.02f, handler));
}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 16, 16);
}
```

this is the Handler class where I get the error, at the last line 
    package wave.myFirstGame;

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Handler {

    LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();

    public void tick() {
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
            tempObject.tick();
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);
            tempObject.render(g);

        }

    }

    public void addObject(GameObject object) {
        this.object.add(object);
    }

    public void removeObject(GameObject object) {
        this.removeObject(object);  //this is the error and the game craches after 1 sec, if i remove it, it works but FPS drops
    }
}
```

and here is the Trail and the problems started when i did this.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Trail extends GameObject  {

    private float alpha = 1;

    private float life;
    private Handler handler;
    private Color color;
    private int width, height;

    //life value between  0.001 - 0.1

    public Trail(int x, int y, ID id , Color color, int width, int height, float life, Handler handler) { // constructor
        super(x, y, id);
        this.handler = handler;
        this.color = color;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.life = life;
    }


    public void tick() {
        if(alpha > life){
            alpha -= (life - 0.001f);
        }
        else handler.removeObject(this);

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setComposite(makeTransparent(alpha));
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        g2d.setComposite(makeTransparent(1)); // we wanna sandwitch our alpha and 1

    }

    private AlphaComposite makeTransparent(float alpha){

        int type = AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER;
        return(AlphaComposite.getInstance(type, alpha));
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {

        return null;
    }



}
```

It's a lot of code i know but I can't find the problem, so if you have any suggestions or ideas it would be great to hear them.
Thank you!

Comment: This is some arbitrary code that has nothing to do with anything fps-related. Where does your code render anything? Where's your ``main``? How many objects are in your list?

Comment: Side note: you might want to learn about writing "reasonable" java code. For example you could rewrite the body of your tick method to `for (GameObject game : object) { game.tick(); }` . No need for an counter and temp object. And: **improve** your naming. Use names that say what the thing is. You know, like calling your `List<GameObject>` gameObjects instead of "object". Can you spot the difference that that would make?! And you know: the fact that you are using the **same** name "object" all over the place is **extremely** bad practice.

Comment: **Finally: there is no need to use bold face all over your question. We are able to read without your bold support.**

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you very much for the feedback and information you provided, it's really helpful.
I'm a newbie and  learned everything online, I want to code every day so i learn as much as I can and get the writing skills on the go. 
Do you have any advice on how to improve my writing?

Comment: @f1sh you're right the post wasn't that good, next time i'll take your feedback in consideration. Thanks!

Comment: @AlinMureșan Standard answer: acquire "Clean code" by Robert Martin and study it carefully. And: find experienced programmers around you, and ask them to review your code. Or, put up (working) code on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you! This is very useful information for me!
Have a great day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void removeObject(GameObject object) {
    this.removeObject(object);  //this is the error and the game craches after 1 sec, if i remove it, it works but FPS drops
}
```

You call the method inside the method -> `StackOverflowError`

It should be:

```
public void removeObject(GameObject object) {
    this.object.remove(object);  //this is the error and the game craches after 1 sec, if i remove it, it works but FPS drops
}
```

Also, you add a new `Trail` object each tick, and never remove it, so you might run out of memory. Try to add it once, in the constructor, and then change its `x` and `y` using getters and setters.

Comment: Oh, never would have noticed that, Thank you so much, it works now! FPS is stable with no drops.

Comment: I'll accept your answer in 10 min because i can't yet. too soon, haha

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell us what the error is, but I suspect it's a stack overflow. This is because you call `removeObject()` from itself repeatedly and forever.

Change

```
this.removeObject(object);
```

to

```
this.object.remove(object);
```

I would also recommend changing the name of `LinkedList<GameObject> object` to `LinkedList<GameObject> objects` since it is a collection of multiple objects, and it will help reduce confusion within your `addObject()` and `removeObject()` functions where the parameter has the same name.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is a potential leak:

`handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y,ID.Trail, Color.red, 16, 16, 0.02f, handler));`

You are creating a new object of type `Trail` at each tick.
This could cause slowness.. and later the crash.

are you sure you can't reuse the object?

Comment: @Nasso got it, it was this.removeObject(object); should have been this.object.remove(object);

Thanks